# not applicable WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have a problem.
I tried to read file system, but `directory.listFiles()` returns `null`
I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to Manifest, but problem remained.
I added `int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);` its return -1.

I use android studio 2.2.2.
AVD: Nexus 5 , API 25, Android 7.1.1 (Google APIs).
Here you can get my project [MyApplication22](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgn0esml47gfdb2/MyApplication22.7z?dl=0)

Comment: did you add SDcard on your AVD?

Comment: No, i didnt add SDcard to my AVD.